# navigation.navigate is not a function... how can i resolve?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

naviate in

```
            useEffect(() => {
                if (me === null) {
                    navigation.navigate('Login');
                }
            },[me]);
```

but this error ocrrue

[image]

here is my code

```
             import React, {useCallback, useEffect, useLayoutEffect} from 'react';
            import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
            import styled from 'styled-components/native';
            import {LOAD_MY_INFO_REQUEST, logoutRequestAction} from '../../../reducers/user';
            import {INITIAL_REQUEST} from '../../../reducers/post';
            import Button from '../../components/Button';
            const Container = styled.Text``;



            const Main = (navigation) => {

                
            const {me} = useSelector((state) => state?.user);

            // console.log("me:",me);


            useEffect(() => {
                if (me === null) {
                    navigation.navigate('Login');
                }
            },[me]);

                const dispatch = useDispatch();
                
                const onLogout = useCallback(() => {
                    dispatch(logoutRequestAction());
                }, []);
                
                return (
                <Container>

            <Button
                    type="primary"
                    htmlType="submit"
                    label="로그아웃"
                    style={{marginBottom: 24}}
                    onPress={onLogout}
                    />
                    
                </Container>
                );
            };

            export default Main;
```

i don't know what is wrong.....

Comment: Can you please show what is inside `navigation` prop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this

```
const Main = ({
    navigation
  }) => { // use {} to object destructuring
    useEffect(() => {
      if (!me) { // just check null by using !
        navigation.navigate('Login');
      }
    }, [me]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, components provide a navigation object but that is inside of the props object and you are trying to access navigation directly not from the props that are why it's saying the function is not defined.

**You can change this**

```
   const Main = (navigation) => {...
```

**to this**

```
const Main = (props) => {

// destructuring from props.

     const {navigation} = props

....

}
```

**or**

```
// Here you directly destructing the navigation from props
  const Main = ({navigation}) => {...

        useEffect(() => {
                if (me === null) {
                    navigation.navigate('Login');
                }
            },[me]);

.....
}
```

**Complete code:**

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import styled from "styled-components/native";
import {
  LOAD_MY_INFO_REQUEST,
  logoutRequestAction,
} from "../../../reducers/user";
import { INITIAL_REQUEST } from "../../../reducers/post";
import Button from "../../components/Button";
const Container = styled.Text``;

const Main = (props) => {
  const { navigation } = props;

  const { me } = useSelector((state) => state?.user);

  // console.log("me:",me);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (me === null) {
      navigation.navigate("Login");
    }
  }, [me]);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onLogout = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(logoutRequestAction());
  }, []);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Button
        type="primary"
        htmlType="submit"
        label="로그아웃"
        style={{ marginBottom: 24 }}
        onPress={onLogout}
      />
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

***I hope this will help you out. Goodluck!***